# How to communicate from iframe page with its hosting page?

Tags: asp.net

In my web page I have an iframe that displays another page.
I want to pass some parameters from the iframe to the host page.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With server side code (you did tag this asp.net)? No. The page including the iframe loads first, so it can pass data to the page in the iframe (via a query string), but not the other way around.

With client side code? See [How do I communicate between frames in a web browser?](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/#frameRef) but be aware of the limitations of the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you can pass values from a fame/iframe to its parent using javascript using window.parent

Answer (score 1):

An iframe is like a browser within a browser. It's got access to its own cookies, javascript and everything else without nothing to do with the containing page so you really can't do much communication (not from within to without).

If you want to communicate then you can't use iframe. You'd be better with javascript based code.