# iFrame Widget get URL and IP Address

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, iframe

I have a widget that I built that will be put on multiple sites as an iFrame calling a PHP page. I need to save the IP address and URL of where the widget is being used.

iFrame:

```
<iframe frameborder='0' width='620' height='620' src='http://example.com/widget.php?rid=22'></iframe>
```

Right now I am trying:

```
$ip_address = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

This keeps returning the same information which is from where my PHP file is located.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not think you can do it, because of the Origin policy : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy.

Comment: You could try `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but it is not very reliable as it is set by the browser / user agent.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about ip address, but you could get at least the parent location using javascript's parent.  eg:

```
parent.location.href
```

Answer (score 2):

An inline frame, an iframe, looks in on another page.  It does not make that code segment a part of the page holding the iframe.  It's framing, but not actually including, the content pointed to in the src attribute.  This is part of the "nested browsing context."  It's nested, to the eyes of the viewer.  However, the parts are where they were stored.  This is part of why the server is reporting the address of the page where the file is located.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-iframe-element.html#the-iframe-element

Answer (score 0):

An iframe just includes a part of any external web application in another one.

It means that the **server-side** code executed in the iframe is on the **hosting server**.

So you **cannot** access --- fortunately ! --- to the embedding server server-side code, for instance PHP global variables.

The only thing you can try (and it's not a clean or working-guarantee way, because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)), is to ask in javascript some informations about the client-side embedded application.
In Javascript, you can access the current URL, but not the IP address, unless the embedding server-side code allow you to do that.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334045/how-to-communicate-from-iframe-page-with-its-hosting-page) :

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, but I got it working with this...

```
var iframe = (parent !== window);
var url = null;

if(iframe) {
    url = document.referrer;
    ref = url.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1];
}
```

The "url" variable will return the full url & page the iFrame is on while "ref" will return just the domain.